# pipe data from kubectl command to terminal in go

Tags: go

I am creating a CLI, what I am trying to do is to pipe the output of the gcloud command to the terminal where it's being executed.

for example one might do the command `$ cli <MICRO_SERVICE> --branch staging --tail 1000 --since 2022-04-20T15:39:00Z`

this is what I have written for the code:

```golang
    logsFormat := fmt.Sprintf("kubectl logs -n <NAME_SPACE> --container=%s -f --timestamps=true --since-time=%s --tail %d -l app=%s", app, since, tail, app)
    logsCmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", logsFormat)

    logsstderr, err := logsCmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err = logsCmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer logsCmd.Wait()
    go io.Copy(os.Stdout, logsstderr)
```

when I run the command I get no errors from `kubectl` but I don't see the logs from that microservice. What I suspect is that I am missing the proper way of piping the data being returned from `kubectl` to the terminal

Answer (score 1):

I updated it to:

```golang
    logsFormat := fmt.Sprintf("kubectl logs -n <NAME_SPACE> --container=%s -f --timestamps=true --since-time=%s --tail %d -l app=%s", app, since, tail, app)
    logsCmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", logsFormat)

    stdOut, err := logsCmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = logsCmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    buf := bufio.NewReader(stdOut)

    for {
        line, _, err := buf.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(string(line))
    }
```

using `buf := bufio.NewReader(stdOut)` was the main change